# Edge Cases for the X-Forwarded-For Header?

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to know what the edge cases for the X-Forwarded-For header is. Usually it has the format `X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2`.

Since this is Http we talk about and a server needs to respect all the weirdness that exists in the wild, I want to know what edge cases exist.

Normally the header contains IP addresses (to my knowledge) but what else can it contain? Does some clients use domain names? Can there be empty entries in the list? Anyone have seen something different than an IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw just ip addresses. Still, it is not "real" standard, and, as you said, "server needs to respect all the weirdness that exists in the wild". The answer is obvious:

Does some clients use domain names?

Yes

**Can there be empty entries in the list?**

Yes

**Anyone have seen something different than an IP?**

I did not see, I even did not try to look for.

Answer (score 0):

While the HTTP protocol gives an exhaustive description of the supported values for this header (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#section-6), a server should be prepared for anything that comes from a client.
You should therefore expect the header to effectively have **any** possible value.

If it is not a list of node identifiers as defined in the RFC, it has most likely been forged by the client, and the best course of action is to return an error 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: This RFC is a draft, so it is not quite into production, right? Specifying alias to disguise the ip but make the entity identifiable is a good idea but does not apply to the XForwaredFor header. Thanks for the info. Do you know any time frame when this RFC might become an official standard?

Comment: Well, this is a "de facto" standard, because it is mostly derived from actual implementations (namely Squid). However, I am not sure how official X-prefixed headers can be seen, given that the general feeling of the community is more about deprecating them. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648. It is more likely that it will evolve into "Forwarded: for=192.0.2.43" as seen in the aforementioned RFC 7239.

Comment: That are very interesting information. Thanks a lot!